# Google map api initialize: initialize is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I get   error in my console when using google map api:-Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize is not defined
Any help please ?

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {


 var myLatLng = {lat: 42.52501, lng: 2.938979}; 
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 12,
    center: myLatLng,
    scrollwheel: false,
    draggable:true,



  });
     var image='logo.png';
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon:image

  });
}
</script>
```

**HEADER.PHP**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key='YOUR API KEY HERE'"></script>

<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp'></script>

<body  onload="initialize()";></body>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You call two time  the google maps api , have body without code and is not clear where is placed the script with initialize function ...

i have played a litte with your code  ..

**HEADER.PHP**

```
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp'></script>

<body>

  <div id="map" style="height:500px; width:500px;"></div>
  <script>

    function initialize() {


     var myLatLng = {lat: 42.52501, lng: 2.938979}; 
         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: myLatLng,
        scrollwheel: false,
        draggable:true,



      });
         var image='logo.png';
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon:image

      });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm using another template

Comment: What di you mean ? ..you are not able to place the code in right source/file?  update you question with you template or files involved ...so i can suggestion where place the code .. ..

Comment: i'm using wordpress, i was created new page template which contains script google map

Comment: i get error in my console :You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors. when i put code in header any idea ?

Comment: Try removing  the first script <script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp'></script>

Comment: any idea with this error please  ? Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null

Comment: This error message is not related to the code posted in answer .. could be related to you wordpress app .. eventually show the related code ..